# Bend gradient CSS line or SVG image or path line under a word that keeps the width to 100%

Tags: css, svg, line, gradient

I am trying to add a CSS gradient line (that is slightly bended in the middle) on specific text that keeps the height the same and width should match 100% the same as "position relative" text.

What I want to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d6Ur.jpg

I managed to do the following progress below, but I can't find a way to bend that line using transform.

```css
.gradient_text {
    background: linear-gradient(90.34deg, #1FA30A 0.2%, #B9D124 70.4%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-clip: text;
    text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}
.gradient_text:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 102%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: linear-gradient(90.34deg, #1FA30A 0.2%, #B9D124 70.4%);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
h2 { font-size: 64px; color: #000; font-family: Arial; }
```

```html
<h2>Lorem <span class="gradient_text green">ipsum</span> dolor sit!</h2>
```

Comment: 2dd transforms are always affine so you can't bend things.

Comment: Can I achieve that bend effect with something else?

Comment: draw a bent line with a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a one-off solution, you can draw the "bent" line as a SVG `<path>`. But that solution does not lend itself to easy reuse. Two factors limit what can be done:

1. Sizing the line width depends on the use of font-relative sizes, i. e. `em`. That means the SVG part needs to be part of the CSSOM or at least being able to inherit properties from document stylesheets. That precludes the use of  a `:after` pseudo-element with `content: url(image:svg+xml,...)`, which would encapsulate the image. The markup for the SVG has to be placed inline, intermingled with your text.
2. Gradient definitions in [CSS](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-images-3/#gradients) and [SVG](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/pservers.html#Gradients) do not mix. They can be translated into one another, but neither will a `background: url(#gradient)` referencing a SVG gradient paint server work on a HTML element, nor can you write `stroke: linear-gradient(...)` for a SVG `<path>`. Both definitions need to be spelled out, despite describing the same gradient.

I've placed the SVG gradient definition and a template for the line in separate elements, so you can at least mix-and match different gradients with (potentially) different line definitions. The one defined here will stretch horizontally to always span the text length of its parent element, but maintain its `stroke-width` in relation to font size. Use the `.gradient_text svg` properties to fine-tune the position of the line.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #000; 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  margin: 0;
}
#gradient-line {
  overflow: visible;
}
#gradient-line path {
  vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 0.2em;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
.gradient_text {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #1FA30A 0.2%, #B9D124 70.4%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: relative;
}
.gradient_text svg {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  left: 0.1em;
  top: 1em;
  width: calc(100% - 0.2em);
  height: 0.5em;
}
.gradient_text.green svg {
  stroke: url(#gradient-green);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <linearGradient id="gradient-green">
    <stop offset="0.002" stop-color="#1FA30A" />
    <stop offset="0.704" stop-color="#B9D124" />
  </linearGradient>
  <symbol id="gradient-line" viewBox="0 0 10 5" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0,4Q5,1 10,1" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
<h2>Lorem <span class="gradient_text green">ipsum<svg><use href="#gradient-line" /></svg></span> dolor sit!</h2>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for! Reusable elements with different colors and stretches as long as the word. Marked as solution!